# Reading XML in java using DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am new to read XML in Java using DOM. Could someone help me with simple code steps to read this XML in DOM?

Here is my XML:

```
<DataSet xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='datamartschema.1.3.xsd'>
<DataStream title='QUESTIONNAIRE'>
<Record>
<TransactionDate>2014-05-28T14:17:31.2186777-06:00</TransactionDate><SubType>xhaksdj</SubType>
<IntegerValue title='ComponentID'>11111</IntegerValue>
</Record><Record>
<TransactionDate>2014-05-28T14:17:31.2186777-06:00</TransactionDate><SubType>jhgjhg</SubType>
<IntegerValue title='ComponentID'>11111</IntegerValue>
</Record>
</DataStream>
</DataSet>
```

In this XML I need to read the DataStream value and Record values. My expected output is

```
DataStream=QUESTIONNAIRE and my records are 
<TransactionDate>2014-05-28T14:17:31.2186777-06:00</TransactionDate><SubType>xhaksdj</SubType><IntegerValue title='ComponentID'>11111</IntegerValue><TransactionDate>2014-05-28T14:17:31.2186777-06:00</TransactionDate><SubType>jhgjhg</SubType><IntegerValue title='ComponentID'>11111</IntegerValue>
```

How can I get this output? I tried myself but I can't get the records output like above. I get the output without Tags which are present in the above output.I am using this line to get the output. But it does not give me correct output. Also, how to read the datastream value from this XML? Kindly help me.

**This is my code snippets**

```
NodeList datasetallRecords = indElement.getElementsByTagName("Record");
for (int y = 0; y < datasetallRecords.getLength(); y++) {
    Element recordsElement = (Element) datasetallRecords.item(y);

    recordXMl = recordXMl + recordsElement.getTextContent();
    String d = datasetallRecords.item(y).getTextContent();
    if (recordsElement.getTagName().equalsIgnoreCase("SubType")) {
        lsDataStreamSubTypes.add(recordsElement.getTextContent());
    }
    recordCount = y;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create new instance of builder you can get **DataStream**
it would be look like this:

```
 Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
 NodeList dataStreams = root.getElementsByTagName("DataStream");
```

then get throw this list and get all info like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataStreams.lenght(); i++) {
         Element dataStream = (Element) dataStreams.item(i);
         if (dataStream.getNodeType() == Element.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                     String title = dataStream.getAttributes()
                                              .getNamedItem("title").getTextContent();
         }
}
```

Comment: Kindly help me to get the record values with tags which is present in the above question.Aleksei Bulgak

Comment: I know only one decision. You need to get names and attributes of this fields and then form using this info such code view. Also you can get all children of node so you can go through children and form such kind of info about records.Use this method of Node : `node.getChildNodes()`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a Node like this

```
Node nNode = datasetallRecords.item(y);
```

then an element like this

```
Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
```

now you can start taking the values from the element by using the getelementbyid and getnodevalue method.

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting the tags because the call to `getTextContent()` on the "Record" node will return *only* the textual content of that node and its descendants.

If you need to nodes as well you'll have to process the XML by hand. Have a look at the [DOM tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/index.html) it covers processing a document in DOM mode very well including how to read out element names.

Comment: kindly Give me the simple code to get the record values with tags from the above XML.